# why is the output not a float

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am wondering why `y` is being returned as an array.  If it helps, `x` is a numpy array.

I have not gotten to the bit where I have to store the `y` values in an array yet, but I am trying to find the average of `N_obs_photon(t)` over a finely scaled grid to give a smoothed graph of `N_obs_photon(t)` over a coarsely scaled grid. I think that the part with the `sum(array)/len(array)` should be giving me a float but instead it is returning an array (more correctly 1001 arrays). Even if I try setting `x` to some array with only one value, `y` is still being returned as an array. And how should I write it so that I am being given the average for `y`?

```
x = np.linspace(0,1,1001)

ftc = 11
L = 10**(-3)
i = x/L

j = np.arange(0,11001,1) #end number is max(i)*ftc + 1

'''reference:
fine_grid_number = j
coarse_grid_number = i
coase_grid_width = L
fine_grid_width = L/ftc #denominator is ftc 
coarse_grid_position = i*L
fine_grid_position = j*L/ftc #denominator is ftc'''

#Plan is to create an array of y values, then plot x vs y

for n in i:
    q = np.arange(-0.5*(ftc-1),0.5*ftc,1)
    #temp_array = np.empty([])
    temp_array = []
    for w in q:
        t = ftc*n + w #t is fine grid number
        t = t*L/ftc #convert to fine grid position
        if t < 0: #drop t when it would be less than zero
            t = 0
            temp_array.append(t) #add to array
        else:
            t = N_obs_photon(t)   #take through function
            temp_array.append(t) #add to array
    y = sum(temp_array)/len(temp_array) #average the array

    print(y) #test if y is a number

    #store result in y array
```

Comment: I do not see how can `y` be an array. When I run your code, I do not get `y` as an array either. It is a scalar printed many times because of the print statement inside a loop. No surprises here.

Comment: What did you use for N_obs_photon(t)?

Comment: What _should_ I use for `N_obs_photon(t)`? If this is an important piece of information, please consider including it into your question.